# How to Build Project for 2 platform in single build

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2019

**Is it possible to build a project for 2 platforms using a single command**?

I have a solution with 2 active platforms i need to build each project for both platforms.

Solution containing both C++ & C#

All project have different output folder per active platform

Is it possible?

Do i need to add a post build event and rerun the compilation?

[Active Platforms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DnFr.png)

Comment: I think you can use `Batch Build` button in VS IDE to build different projects with different platforms, configurations,etc.. at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to build a project for 2 platforms using a single
>   command?

It can be done in Visual Studio.

**1) In VS IDE**,

there is an option called [Batch Build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-build-multiple-configurations-simultaneously?view=vs-2019) which can build different projects with different platforms,..etc at the same time.

**Build**-->**Batch Build** or right-click your solution-->**Batch Build**

[image]

You can choose any platforms for your project to build them.

**2) If you want to use MSBuild command line**,

You can create a proj called `test.proj` file which assembles the association between the project and the platform.

Then build `test.proj` in msbuild command line directly.

You can check [my answer in a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61768037/12450747).

In my answer, `BuildInParallel="true"` can build all projects in parallel, which can improve the performance of msbuild build.

Comment: I did not know about such option , testing it today , we have about 720 projects and 130 have dual configurations - currently i get many issues of rebuild