# vcvars file access denied in parallel workers

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, gitlab-ci-runner, parallel-builds

I get this kind of error sometimes in gitlab ci-cd worker log.

How can I fix it and set up parallel builds for MSVC projects?

```
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2019 Developer Command Prompt v16.8.4
** Copyright (c) 2020 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
[vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x64'
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

Answer (score 0):

I am curious how you invoke msbuild.exe, and maybe you have invoke multiple mbsuild.exe processes to correspond to the one-to-one construction projects.

**If** you simply receive external programs that interfere with msbuild.exe, before you faced this, you should open **Task Manager** to shut down any process with uses `msbuild.exe`.

If you just start multiple msbuild.exe processes under gitlab ci-cd and then face the issue(you already checked that there is no other programs using msbuild.exe under Task Manager), you have changed to use another function:

Create a file called `test.proj` file and then use [my method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61726964/how-can-you-build-multiple-c-visual-studio-v2015-configurations-in-parallel-u/61768037#61768037) to add any project files(`csproj` file) or solution files(`sln` file) which you want to parallel built into `test.proj` file. So that you only need to input  one `proj` file into ci-cd.

Use `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe xxx\test.proj -t:ParelBuild` under gitlab ci-cd.

Comment: It occurse before launch of msbuild, i can't execute vcvarsall.bat

Comment: Did you check task manager to make sure you have shut any processes which used `msbuild.exe` before that?

Comment: I can't check it by hands, because it starting by runner, and I need some explanation, what can I do for launching vcvars.bat  and msbuild in parallel on differents projects, at the same time, without conflicts.

Comment: That is related your bat file and your ci-cd command. Try a restart of your agent.

Comment: I try it already, and it doesn't help. And this error rarely displayed, so it looks like, this bat(vcvarsall) can be run only one in parallel...

Comment: You have to run them one by one.

Comment: I need parallel build, not sequenced, for different project solutions, not one.